# Sed -e 'Unterminated 's' command

Tags: sed

Im trying to escape all the backslashes from some text generated by figlet.
Here is what I have so far.

```
figlet -f $font -t "Foo Bar" | sed -e "s|\\|\\\\|g"
```

This doesn't work for some reason, but this does.

```
figlet -f $font -t "Foo Bar" | sed -e "s| |X|g"
```

Am I misunderstanding how sed works here? I couldn't find similar posts about this either.

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes do not protect the backslashes that are inside the `sed -e "s|\\|\\\\|g"` from the shell's attempts to parse them. If you use a simpler example you can see this a bit more easily:

```
$ echo 'blah\blah'| sed -e "s|\\|blah|g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command

$ echo 'blah\blah'| sed -e 's|\\|blah|g'
blahblahblah
```

If you want to use the first form of your `sed` you need to switch it to single quotes instead of double.

```
$ figlet -t "Foo Bar" | sed -e 's|\\|\\\\|g'
 _____             ____
|  ___|__   ___   | __ )  __ _ _ __
| |_ / _ \\ / _ \\  |  _ \\ / _` | '__|
|  _| (_) | (_) | | |_) | (_| | |
|_|  \\___/ \\___/  |____/ \\__,_|_|
```

If you have to use double quotes, then you need more backslashes to escape the shell and `sed`:

```
$ figlet -t "Foo Bar" | sed -e "s|\\\|\\\\\\\|g"
 _____             ____
|  ___|__   ___   | __ )  __ _ _ __
| |_ / _ \\ / _ \\  |  _ \\ / _` | '__|
|  _| (_) | (_) | | |_) | (_| | |
|_|  \\___/ \\___/  |____/ \\__,_|_|
```

Comment: Oh wow thats interesting. So everything works fine now that I'm in single quotes. But what if I want to also add environment variables in there? I can't do that with single quotes (I don't need it for what I'm working on, but I'm curious of how to get around this)

Comment: @AmleshSivanantham - you have to escape the backslashes with more if you want to use double quotes.